# Count accepted conditions with linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I´m try to implement a search for my database who is searching in a lot of columns. For the output i want to sort the results about how often the search value is appear in different coumns.

For example i have a query like:

```
from model in dataContext.Models
where model.Name.Equals(value) || model.Description.Contains(Value)
select model
```

is it possible to add a variable, maybe in the entity, that store a counter who is count +1 for each `true` where clause.

In the example, if the value test is in `model.Name` and `model.Description` i would have a count of 2 if only in `model.Name` it´s 1 and so on.

So in simple c# it would be doing the work of this method:

```
public List<Object> GetAllModelsWithValue(string value)
{
    List<Object> Models = new List<Object>();
    forach(var model in dataContext.Models)
    {
        var count =0;
        var modelCorrect = false;
        if( model.Name.Equals(value))
        {
            count =+1;
            modelCorrect = true;
        }
        if(model.Description.Contains(Value))
        {
            count =+1;
            modelCorrect = true;
        }
        if(modelCorrect )
        {
            Models.Add(new{model,count});
        }
    return Models;
}
```

The exact model seems not to be relevant for the question. We can imagine a model like:

```
[Table(Name = "Model")]
public class Model
{
    [Column(Name = "Model_ID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync =  AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "Model_Name", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "Model_Description", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

An search outside sql will slow down the search a lot, so my idea was to bring the search in the sql.

Comment: could you please post the definition of the model and a concrete example of what you have and what you want? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating new type including information about matches?
For example:

```
from model in dc.Models
where model.Name.Equals(value) || model.Description.Contains(value)
select new ModelMatches
{
    Matches = (model.Name.Equals(value) ? 1 : 0) + (model.Description.Contains(value) ? 1 : 0),
    Model = model
};

public class ModelMatches
{
    public Model Model { get; set; }
    public int Matches { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you need to identify WHICH columns matched, you could calculate some bit mask based on matches.

Comment: That don´t run in Linq to SQL because you can´t call non sql methods.

Comment: Oh I forgot about that restriction of Linq2Sql. Than just denormalize the function. Fixed in the answer to avoid mess.